# Is it possible to extract the user interface from an android emulator as a video source and convert it to mp4?

Tags: android, mp4, android-virtual-device, remote-desktop

I was wondering if it is possible to extract what you are seeing when using an android emulator as a video source and then convert it into an mp4 stream.
It should be possible as remote desktop clients are able to somehow get the screen information of one machine and display it onto the application.

Thanks in advance!

I am unsure how I should approach this problem as I do not know what to search for.

Comment: **(1)** Ask about a **real problem** regarding the thing(s) you need to fix. We don't know your operating system, we don't know your emulator...  Should we also guess if it is possible for you? At least here you mentioned in wanting MP4 output, others don't. **(2)** Find a screen recorder that records applications / windows. Then record the window running the emulator application.

Comment: PS: See how the current Answer assumes maybe you're using Android Studio.. I suspect Windows OS. Really though, nobody knows, so good luck waiting for an Answer when you give no useful **technical details** (_eg:_ about what does what/where/how/etc... ).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you're using Android Studio, there's a screen record button in logcat.
You can record video or capture image.